# Como aplicar Pathfinding em uma estrutura de nós?

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, lógica

Eu tenho uma estrutura de nós que representam as minhas páginas e suas ligações, por exemplo, da página A eu posso ir para página B ou página C. Além de que eu posso ter a página A apontando para a B que aponta para C que aponta novamente para A.
O que preciso fazer é determinar uma página de origem e outra de destino, e exibir somente os nós relacionados, por exemplo saindo de A, chegar até H.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual algoritmo é utilizado para achar este tipo de caminho?

Answer (score 3):

Existem vários algorítimos para essa finalidade, dentre eles (tudo em inglês):

[Dijkstra's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Eis um exemplo em pseudo-código retirado do link:

```
function Dijkstra(Graph, source):

       create vertex set Q

       for each vertex v in Graph:             
           dist[v] ← INFINITY
           prev[v] ← UNDEFINED
           add v to Q

      dist[source] ← 0

      while Q is not empty:
          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]
          remove u from Q 

          for each neighbor v of u:           
              alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
              if alt < dist[v]:
                  dist[v] ← alt 
                  prev[v] ← u 

      return dist[], prev[]
```

[D*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*) Algorítimo D-Star

Algorítimo [Any-angle path planning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any-angle_path_planning)

[A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) Algorítimo A-Star

Comment: Para mim um link já daria encaminhamento a resposta, mas existe uma discussão interessante sobre isso na comunidade:  http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links

Comment: @Pagotti a pergunta é tão direta quanto a resposta : "Qual algoritmo é utilizado para achar este tipo de caminho?", e ainda pensado nisso tive o cuidado de transferir o algorítimo do link para minha resposta. No mais, mesmo que os links se quebrem a resposta estará correta, pois essas técnicas são como padrões e sempre estarão presentes para consulta.

Comment: tranquilo, como eu disse, para mim seria suficiente. Eu comentei por ser uma preocupação do SO e também ter tido uma discussão sobre isso aqui no SOpt.

Comment: O que eu poderia responder ? Se eu colocasse só os nomes, sem os links, tmb estaria correto ao meu ver... Esse tipo de preocupação se dá quando a resposta propriamente dita está no link, o que não é o caso... Mas entendo sua observação, só acho que por ser uma pergunta objetiva, a resposta pode ser também...